# JavaScript: Does an async function create a new thread?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, function, asynchronous

Mozilla’s documentation on `XMLHttpRequest` includes the following on the `async` parameter:

> Note: Synchronous requests on the main thread can be easily disruptive to the user experience and should be avoided; in fact, many browsers have deprecated synchronous XHR support on the main thread entirely.

That makes sense, as you don’t what to hold up the main thread waiting for an indeterminate period of time.

If I create an `async` function which includes usng `XMLHttpRequest`, would that qualify as a new thread?

I know about `fetch()`, I know about promises, and I know about using `XMLHttpRequest` with callbacks. This question is about the `async` keyword.

Comment: The internals of various asynchronous sources (like XHR) is an implementation detail. It could use threads, or the whole environment could be select-poll clean. **tldr:** From JavaScript, the guarantee is that the execution is a single-threaded model - that includes all sync callbacks.

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript (in the browser) is entirely single-threaded (with the exception of WebWorkers). The term "asynchronous" doesn't necessarily have anything to do with being multi-threaded.

The network fetch likely happens on browser "networking" thread in a higher performance language (c++, rust, etc.), but this means nothing to JavaScript.

What synchronous means in JavaScript terms is that the c++ code that handles the actual network request will pause the JavaScript event loop until the request completes. That means absolutely nothing can happen in the JavaScript context until the request finishes.

Therefore async means that you can do other things on the single JavaScript thread while the network fetch happens in the background. This is facilitated by c++ calling a JavaScript callback or resolving a JavaScript Promise (aka async/await).

I will try to elaborate more clearly in pseudocode:

```js
const response = makeRequest({ asyncMode: false });
//nothing can happen until this request finishes
//requestAnimationFrame animation code or click event listeners will not run
// until the request is finished
```

```js
makeRequest({ asyncMode: true, callback: function(response, error){ console.log("this will execute later once the network request is made") } });
console.log("this code will run right away");
//requestAnimationFrame animation code or click event listeners will run as normal
//  during the request
```

Comment: For a better and more in depth explanation I would recommend this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0